# How do include a javascript function in the animate queue?

Tags: jquery

How do I include a Javascript function in the middle of the animate queue? For example I would like to call `alert()` in between these two jQuery functions to animate the height property:

```
 $('#divContainer').animate({ height: "200px" }, 'slow').alert('alert goes here').animate({ height: "50px" }, 'slow');
```

Comment: Do you want the alert _between_ the animation or during or after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what [`.queue()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue2) is for:

```
$('#divContainer')
  .animate({ height: "200px" }, 'slow')
  .queue(function(next){
      alert('alert goes here');
      next();
  })
  .animate({ height: "50px" }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$('#divContainer').animate({ height: "200px" }, 'slow', function() { alert('alert goes here'); }).animate({ height: "50px" }, 'slow');
```

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for animate specifies you can pass a callback.